# How to refresh the page without it reloading as a new one?

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I am currently trying to use connect-flash to send flash messages to the same page

```
req.flash('error_login', 'Incorrect Username/Password');
res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
```

In doing this I effectively reload the page so that the flash message becomes present. The issue I have now is if, after forcing several reloads, by triggering this "login error" several times, when I press the back button on the browser it does not go to the previous page, but one of the reloaded versions of this page.

So my history looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ECw.png)